# Is there any WordPress Plugin that provides video editing from front end side?

Tags: plugins, php

Is it possible to incorporate video editing functionality in the front end of the WordPress website using any plugin (free or paid)?
For example, if we have a website where we submit a form that captures all data including media (videos), so is there any plugin which helps in editing/trimming the video (or capturing screenshots etc) while uploading.

Thanks.